# Use an OxyImage from a Resource in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I like to use an ImageAnnotation in a OxyPlot chart using Xamarin.Forms.

My problem is that ImageAnnotation wants an OxyImage and to create an OxyImage I need a byte array or a string.

If I want to use an image I use that code (at the moment I tested it only with Android and works):

```
ImageSource iso = ImageSource.FromFile("myImage.png");
```

How I can create an oxyImage from my resources?

Thanks,
Enrico

Answer (score 0):

If all you need is a byte array you could open the image as a file and get the byte arrays from it.

The only problem is that since you are using Forms this will require you to handle the File System in each platform independently.

[This](https://components.xamarin.com/view/pclstorage) library did this but it seems to be outdated, probably you could give it a try and see if it works for you or simply take some ideas of how to make your own implementation works as you only need to read the file and return the bytes.

Something like:

```
 var myImageInByteArray = File.ReadAllBytes("myImage.png");
```